# Allow only staff member to delete post and post created by user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

inside views.py can we overide some method inside Postdelete to achieve this i have tried using

```
   class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return super(PostDelete, self).get_queryset()
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693837/django-staff-decorator

Answer (score 0):

This way only Staff  can delete.

```
   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(PostDelete, self).get_object()
        if obj.user != self.request.user and not self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Http404
        else:
            return obj
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```

This way both who created the post and Staff both can delete.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(PostDelete, self).get_object()
        if obj.user != self.request.user and not self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Http404
        else:
            return obj
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')
```